# How to get the values of input text GTK2 + Glade

Tags: c, gtk, glade

When i click in send_button_clicked(); i want to get the values in the entry "entryform1", how i do that? My code below:

```
gtkwidgete1 = GTK_ENTRY( gtk_builder_get_object( gtkBuilder, "chave_Sessao_TextBox" ) );
const gchar *text1 = gtk_entry_get_text(e1);strcpy(ch1,text1);
g_print ("Contents of entries:%s\n", text1);
```

Comment: What is `ch1`? Why do you need to copy the text? what do you want to do with the text. And WHAT IS YOUR QUESTION?

Comment: Did my answer there work for you?  Did you have any problems with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [GNOME's GTK+ 2.0 Documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/x939.html):

> The contents of the Entry can be retrieved by using a call to the following function. This is useful in the callback functions described below:

```
const gchar *gtk_entry_get_text(GtkEntry *entry);
```

It's really as simple as that.  So do something like:

```
GtkWidget *e1 = gtk_entry_new();
/* Set up whatever else you want to with your entry here */
g_signal_connect(e1, "activate", G_CALLBACK(print_message, e1));
gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (yourgtkbox), e1, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
gtk_widget_show(e1);
```

And in your callback function `print_message` print out the message:

```
const gchar *text1 = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY (e1));
g_print ("Entry contents: %s\n", text1);
```

In GTK, `gchar` is just a `typedef` to `char`, so you have no need to copy it into another string.

For more examples, see the link provided.